# i want to create an array of object based on the data i am receiving in my api

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object as the return from the api call. Now I want the data to be in the format as the array of the objects. To do that I return a function but in my output it only shows the last object value not the initial ones

```
 function(error, orders) {
        if(!error){
            let deliveryFee = 0;
            let dateWiseData = [];
            let dateWiseDataObject = {
                dateWiseSum : 0,
                orderCount : 0
            };
            for(let order of orders){
                deliveryFee = order.deliveryFee + deliveryFee;
                if(moment(endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') === moment(order.createdAt).format('YYYY-MM-DD')){
                    dateWiseDataObject.dateWiseSum = order.deliveryFee + dateWiseDataObject.dateWiseSum;
                    dateWiseDataObject.orderCount = 1 + dateWiseDataObject.orderCount; 
                }else{
                    dateWiseData.push(dateWiseDataObject);
                    dateWiseDataObject.dateWiseSum = 0;
                    dateWiseDataObject.orderCount = 0;
                    endDate = moment(endDate, "YYYY-MM-DD").add(1,'days');
                    
                }
            }
            deliveryFee =  (Math.round(deliveryFee * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            let averageShippoAMount = deliveryFee/orders.length;
            averageShippoAMount = (Math.round(averageShippoAMount * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    
            
    
            let data = {
                totalShippoAmount: deliveryFee,
                totalShippoOrders: orders.length,
                averageShippoAMount: averageShippoAMount
            }
            res.send(data)
        }else{
            console.log("something went wrong")
        }
    }
```

my orders is as below

```
[
    {
        "_id": "615156a25a49a90f34a98820",
        "CRV": 0.05,
        "__v": 0,
        "address": {
            "description": "address",
            "_id": "6131b172242dd2113ac43f3b",
            "nearestStore": "Abc",
        },
        "billingAddress": {
            "description": "ABCD"
        },
        "creditCard": "card_",
        "deliverNow": true,
        "deliveryDate": null,
        "deliveryDateObj": "2021-09-27T06:15:52.996Z",
        "deliveryEndTime": null,
        "deliveryFee": 11.24,
        "deliveryNote": "",
        "deliverySlot": "",
        "deliveryStartTime": "now",
        "owner": "60864a4e175bd51d86fb3e8d",
        "selectedShippingObject": "53ccb767de264f56879f9c82e09fefe8",
        "shippingTimeInHours": 0,
        "strDeliveryEndTime": "23:29",
        "strDeliveryStartTime": "22:29",
        "tax": 0.64,
        "tip": 0.67,
        "tipPercentage": 10,
        "updatedAt": "2021-09-27T05:29:11.418Z",        "outForDeliveryAt": null,
        "acceptedAt": null,
        "assignedAt": null,
        "approvedAt": "2021-09-27T05:29:11.417Z",
        "completed": false,
        "refunded": false,
        "shippoOrder": true,
        "createdAt": "2021-09-27T05:29:08.351Z",
        "total": 19.29,
        "subTotal": 6.74,
        "qty": [
            1
        ],
        "products": [
            "611c954c3fcd61ef71be2dea"
        ],
        "status": "Approved"
    },
{
....
}
]
```

I am comparing the createdAt dates and for the same date, I am trying to add the deliveryFee and the number of orders on the particular date and want to return an array of object with both deliveryFee and the order count.
I am getting output as [ { dateWiseSum: 85.53, orderCount: 8 } ] and I am expecting the output to be the [{dateWiseSum: 47.77, orderCount: 4 },{dateWiseSum: 85.53, orderCount: 8 }]
as of my data but I don't know what is wrong with the code, any help would be much appreciated thanks in advance

Comment: Would you be able to show us the data that did not get pushed in?

Comment: I mean only the end loop values are been pushed in

Comment: I think this is because you aren't preserving the initial array, but overwriting it with each item you push in. I'm assuming you mean that there's only one value being pushed into the array?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you aren't preserving the initial array, but overwriting it with each item you push in. I'm assuming you mean that there's only one value being pushed into the array?

If so, this should preserve the array and push items onto the end.

```
for(let order of orders){
                deliveryFee = order.deliveryFee + deliveryFee;
                if(moment(endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') === moment(order.createdAt).format('YYYY-MM-DD')){
                    dateWiseDataObject.dateWiseSum = order.deliveryFee + dateWiseDataObject.dateWiseSum;
                    dateWiseDataObject.orderCount = 1 + dateWiseDataObject.orderCount; 
                }else{
                    dateWiseData.push([...dateWiseData, dateWiseDataObject]);
                    dateWiseDataObject.dateWiseSum = 0;
                    dateWiseDataObject.orderCount = 0;
                    endDate = moment(endDate, "YYYY-MM-DD").add(1,'days');
                    
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you overwrite the object in the array. **An object is always located on the heap and it is passed by reference**.

You need to create a new object inside the local scope and pass it to the array.

```
else {
  dateWiseData.push({...dateWiseDataObject})
  dateWiseDataObject.dateWiseSum = 0;
  dateWiseDataObject.orderCount = 0;
}
```

or

```
else {
  let newObject = {
         dateWiseSum: dateWiseDataObject.dateWiseSum,
         orderCount: dateWiseDataObject.orderCount
  };
  dateWiseData.push(newObject)
  dateWiseDataObject.dateWiseSum = 0;
  dateWiseDataObject.orderCount = 0;
}
```

Another thing, I think I found a bug in your code. When you check for the date in the loop, you will always skip the first order of the next date.

Here is my solution (without library):

```js
let orders = [
    {
        "deliveryFee": 11.24,
        "createdAt": "2021-09-27T05:29:08.351Z"
    },
    {
        "deliveryFee": 10.00,
        "createdAt": "2021-09-27T05:29:08.351Z"
    },
    {
        "deliveryFee": 9.10,
        "createdAt": "2021-09-27T05:29:08.351Z"
    },
    {
        "deliveryFee": 7.24,
        "createdAt": "2021-09-28T05:29:08.351Z"
    },
    {
        "deliveryFee": 4.24,
        "createdAt": "2021-09-28T05:29:08.351Z"
    },
    {
        "deliveryFee": 1.24,
        "createdAt": "2021-09-28T05:29:08.351Z"
    },
    {
        "deliveryFee": 25.24,
        "createdAt": "2021-09-28T05:29:08.351Z"
    }
];

let endDate = new Date("2021-09-27");

let deliveryFee = 0;
let dateWiseData = [];
let dateWiseDataObject = {
    dateWiseSum : 0,
    orderCount : 0
};

//This is the key function to add a new object to the array
function addDataToArray(dateWiseData, dateWiseDataObject){ 
    dateWiseData.push({...dateWiseDataObject});
}

for(let order of orders){
    let orderDate = new Date(order.createdAt);

    if(endDate.getUTCDate() !== orderDate.getUTCDate()){
        addDataToArray(dateWiseData, dateWiseDataObject);

        dateWiseDataObject.dateWiseSum = 0;
        dateWiseDataObject.orderCount = 0;
        endDate = new Date(endDate.setTime(endDate.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
    }

    deliveryFee = order.deliveryFee + deliveryFee;
    dateWiseDataObject.dateWiseSum = Number((order.deliveryFee + dateWiseDataObject.dateWiseSum).toFixed(2));
    dateWiseDataObject.orderCount = 1 + dateWiseDataObject.orderCount;

    if(order === orders[orders.length-1]){
        addDataToArray(dateWiseData, dateWiseDataObject)
    }
}



//Display the data to the screen
let data = "";
dateWiseData.forEach((item)=>{
    data += `{dateWiseSum: ${item.dateWiseSum}, orderCount: ${item.orderCount}}<br>`;
});

document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = data
```

```html
<div id="container" ></div>
```